# Does copying a spell on the stack count as casting it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens if I have [Paradox Engine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bParadox%20Engine%5d) but I use [League Guildmage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLeague%20Guildmage%5d)'s ability. Would Paradox Engine’s ability activate?

Comment: Kind of, but I thought they said copies of spells went on the stack so...

Comment: The "duplicate" questions are not duplicates.  They are similar questions, but one is "yes", the other is "no", and this question is in between them.  The fact that this question was marked a duplicate of two different questions with opposite answers should be a clear sign that the duplicate mark is false.

Comment: This one needs to be reopened. We have not actually got a question about this. We have one about casting a copy, but that is different to copying a spell that's already cast.

Answer (score 6):

**No, the copy is not cast, and would not trigger Paradox Engine.**

From the Gatherer Rulings on [League Guildmage:](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=452935)

> 10/5/2018     The copy is created on the stack, so it’s not “cast.” Abilities that trigger when a player casts a spell won’t trigger.

Paradox engine cares only if you cast the spell, and a copy of a spell made by League Guildmage is not cast.